# Kotlin Constructor from Java Super Class Constructor Access

Tags: java, kotlin

I don't think my Title could be any more confusing. I'm integrating Kotlin into an existing Java project. I have a Java class basically defined like so:

```
class EntityBase {
   private Long id;

   public EntityBase() { }
   public EntityBase(Long id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

Then, I've defined a Kotlin Data Class like so and I'm attempting to hydrate this object from a DTO using a companion method, but I can't access the `EntityBase.id` from this method through object creation:

```
data class Thing(
   val name: String,
   val desc: String
) : EntityBase() {

  companion object {

    fun fromDto(dto: ThingDto) = Thing(
       name = dto.name,
       desc = dto.desc
       id = dto.id // this doesn't work because id isn't part of Thing's constructor
    )

}
```

I can get around this by using constructors instead of companion objects but I'm curious if there is a way to do it that I just don't know about. Still pretty new to Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `id` to your constructor and pass it to the base class constructor when your extend.

```
private data class Thing(
        val name: String,
        val desc: String,
        val id: Long
) : EntityBase(id) {

    companion object {
        fun fromDto(dto: ThingDto) = Thing(
                name = dto.name,
                desc = dto.desc,
                id = dto.id 
        )
    }
}
```

Is that what you mean by "using constructors"? If you want to not have the constructors, you have to use getters/setters in your base class (*NOTE* I would not recommend the following, showing for illustration) --

```
class EntityBase {
   private Long id;

   public EntityBase() { }
   public EntityBase(Long id) { this.id = id; }
   public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
   public Long getId() { return id; }
}
```

Then you can do --

```
private data class Thing(
        val name: String,
        val desc: String
) : EntityBase() {

    companion object {

        fun fromDto(dto: ThingDto) : Thing {
            val thing = Thing(
                    name = dto.name,
                    desc = dto.desc)
            thing.id = dto.id;
            return thing;
        }

    }
}
```

Then, you aren't linking the constructors, but this comes with a big downside - `id` is not part of the data class, `toString`, `copy`, `equals`, etc. will only be generated with the values in the constructor of the `data` class.  If you call `toString` on an object using the above, you'll see it only uses `name` and `desc`.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Your latter example is what I was trying to make it work but I was missing your former solution. Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue @iagreen [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72028886/access-kotlin-constructor-in-java-class) can you assist please