# Access kotlin constructor in JAVA class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Tbh I am not sure what my title should be but it's something close to that. In my android application, I am using a library  [Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper) version 3.3.6 (I know it's old and deprecated but still need to use that for now) it is written in kotlin and my project is in JAVA. In the library, there is a function that has a constructor that holds value I can use kotlin to make it work but not pure JAVA let me explain.

```
.../More Code Above/...

    open class ActivityResult : CropResult, Parcelable {

            constructor(
                originalUri: Uri?,
                uriContent: Uri?,
                error: Exception?,
                cropPoints: FloatArray?,
                cropRect: Rect?,
                rotation: Int,
                wholeImageRect: Rect?,
                sampleSize: Int
            ) : super(
                originalBitmap = null,
                originalUri = originalUri,
                bitmap = null,
                uriContent = uriContent,
                error = error,
                cropPoints = cropPoints!!,
                cropRect = cropRect,
                wholeImageRect = wholeImageRect,
                rotation = rotation,
                sampleSize = sampleSize
            )

            protected constructor(`in`: Parcel) : super(
                originalBitmap = null,
                originalUri = `in`.readParcelable<Parcelable>(Uri::class.java.classLoader) as Uri?,
                bitmap = null,
                uriContent = `in`.readParcelable<Parcelable>(Uri::class.java.classLoader) as Uri?,
                error = `in`.readSerializable() as Exception?,
                cropPoints = `in`.createFloatArray()!!,
                cropRect = `in`.readParcelable<Parcelable>(Rect::class.java.classLoader) as Rect?,
                wholeImageRect = `in`.readParcelable<Parcelable>(Rect::class.java.classLoader) as Rect?,
                rotation = `in`.readInt(),
                sampleSize = `in`.readInt()
            )

            override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
                dest.writeParcelable(originalUri, flags)
                dest.writeParcelable(uriContent, flags)
                dest.writeSerializable(error)
                dest.writeFloatArray(cropPoints)
                dest.writeParcelable(cropRect, flags)
                dest.writeParcelable(wholeImageRect, flags)
                dest.writeInt(rotation)
                dest.writeInt(sampleSize)
            }

            override fun describeContents(): Int = 0

            companion object {

                @JvmField
                val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<ActivityResult?> =
                    object : Parcelable.Creator<ActivityResult?> {
                        override fun createFromParcel(`in`: Parcel): ActivityResult =
                            ActivityResult(`in`)

                        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ActivityResult?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
                    }
            }
        }

        object CancelledResult : CropImageView.CropResult(
            originalBitmap = null,
            originalUri = null,
            bitmap = null,
            uriContent = null,
            error = Exception("cropping has been cancelled by the user"),
            cropPoints = floatArrayOf(),
            cropRect = null,
            wholeImageRect = null,
            rotation = 0,
            sampleSize = 0
        )
    }
```

The above is the main class that gives me the result that I want. And to access the `contentUri`I have created a kotlin class GetUri.kt shown below:

```
    import android.net.Uri
    import com.canhub.cropper.CropImage

    fun CropImage.ActivityResult?.getUri(): Uri? { return this?.uriContent }
```

With the help of the above class in my `MainActivity.java` I can use the `GetUriKt.getUri()` and it's working totally fine.

But the main issue here that is in order to make it work I need to add kotlin compiler in my project and use kotlin file, I know almost all the features of kotlin can be replicated in JAVA so just wanna know how it can be done using JAVA only.

PS: Also the library [Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper) wiki has a migration guide that is now working so I'll use this answer to update that too.

Comment: This function doesn't appear to do anything useful--it's just passing through a call to the `uriContent` getter. Why can't you just directly call `getUriContent()` on the instance of this ActivityResult class in your Java code?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Actually that's the issue I am unable to call `getUriContent()` in the java.

Comment: What error does the IDE give you if you do use that code?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Cannot resolve method

Comment: @Tenfour04 is there a way to pass the similar to the kotlin using JAVA class? and here's the link to the [complete file](https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/3.3.6/cropper/src/main/java/com/canhub/cropper/CropImage.kt) may help

Comment: I'm tinkering with it, and the only thing I can figure is that the library is compiled incorrectly. All the superclass members are invisible, and Java won't even allow the class to be cast to its own superclass (`CropImageView.CropResult`). If this is the case, it's impossible to fix in pure Java. I don't know how this could happen. The other weird thing is that the library includes source code of CropResult, but not for CropImage and ActivityResult, even though they are from the same module.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for taking the time I think if it's not possible with pure Java then I have to adjust with kotlin.

Comment: You might also consider opening an issue on Github. The latest version of the library also exhibits the issue.

Comment: Actually, they have changed the library totally after 3.3.6 so this code is depreciated now